# Scala implicit ordering in abstract type

Tags: scala

I have a list of generics T in a abstract class.

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass[T] {
  type SortOrder
  def getSorterFunc(): T => SortOrder

  def sort(myList: List[T]) = {
    val sortFunc =  getSorterFunc()
    myList.sortBy(sortFunc)
  }
}

object SampleObject extends MyAbstractClass[(String,Int,List[Int])] {
  type SortOrder = (String,Int)

  override def getSorterFunc(): (String,Int,List[Int]) => SortOrder {
   val sortFunc : (String,Int,List[Int]) => SortOrder = {
          case (username, id, addresses) => (username, id)
      }
    sortFunc
  }
}
```

There can be many derived classes from the abstract class. 
I want to do a custom sorting on the list[T]. How to achieve this ?
The above code throws compilation error.

```
No implicit Ordering defined for MyAbstractClass.this.SortOrder.
```

Comment: at a first glance, I don't see how this can even compile since `getSorterFunc` returns `T` which is not defined for `SampleObject`

Comment: That is a mistake. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot achieve this with abstract types. To make generic code that relies on implicit parameters compile, you'd need a context bound, and context bounds can only be passed as type parameters.

Here, I moved your abstract type into a type parameter and added a context bound (note the implicit parameter passed in the constructor):

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass[T, SortOrder](implicit ord: Ordering[SortOrder]) {

  def getSorterFunc(): (T) => SortOrder

  def sort(myList: List[T]) = {
    val sortFunc = getSorterFunc()
    myList.sortBy(sortFunc)
  }
}

object SampleObject extends MyAbstractClass[(String, Int, List[Int]), (String, Int)] {
  def getSorterFunc() = {
    case (username, id, addresses) => (username, id)
  }
}
```

This way the compiler knows in advance that any subclass of `MyAbstractClass` *has* to define its `SortOrder` such that there's a way to sort by it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the missing implicit: it can be abstract, too.

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass[T] {
  type SortOrder
  implicit val ordering: Ordering[SortOrder]
  def getSorterFunc(): T => SortOrder

  def sort(myList: List[T]) = {
    val sortFunc =  getSorterFunc()
    myList.sortBy(sortFunc)
  }
}
```

Of course, the problem with this approach is that using it ends up uglier than the one in Sergey's answer:

```
object SampleObject extends MyAbstractClass[(String, Int, List[Int])] {
  type SortOrder = (String, Int)
  val ordering = implicitly[Ordering[(String, Int)]]
  override def getSorterFunc() = {
    val sortFunc: ((String, Int, List[Int])) => SortOrder = {
      case (username, id, addresses) => (username, id)
    }
    sortFunc
  }
}
```

Plus, if you write `implicit val ordering = implicitly[Ordering[(String, Int)]]`, you'll get into an infinite loop and need to build up the ordering manually instead.